# Let's get critical: Sep 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discusión, site-evaluation

We all love [Spanish Language & Usage Stack Exchange](http://spanish.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [¿Qué son "hornos de tabique" y "mirruña de caudal" en el español de Colombia?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4049/que-significan-esas-palabras-en-el-espanol-de-colombia)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How do you say "billing rate"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4053/how-do-you-say-billing-rate)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [¿Cuál es el significado de la expresión "mala copa"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4059/cual-es-el-significado-de-la-expresion-mala-copa)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How does Spanish handle plurals of numbers?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4090/how-does-spanish-handle-plurals-of-numbers)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Significado de "determinar" en Colombia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/significado-de-determinar-en-colombia)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Qué sigifica la frase 'Dicen que solo se está de más'?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4118/que-sigifica-la-frase-dicen-que-solo-se-esta-de-mas)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Past or future neutral time difference -- does my sentence make sense?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4097/past-or-future-neutral-time-difference-does-my-sentence-make-sense)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Using "datos" to refer to specific points](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4102/using-datos-to-refer-to-specific-points)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Did Spanish have declensions? - ¿Alguna vez se declinó en español?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4020/did-spanish-have-declensions-alguna-vez-se-declino-en-espanol)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [¿Se usa "halar" en vez de "jalar" en algún lugar?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4113/se-usa-halar-en-vez-de-jalar-en-algun-lugar)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)